# Why do similar questions get very different responses on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I am new to Stack Overflow and programming in general. I am here to learn how to get better.

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694892/what-is-fabs-in-objective-c?noredirect=1#comment30994891_20694892) and was ridiculed. But someone asked the inverse [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717060/convert-to-absolute-value-in-objective-c) and was praised. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what way were you "ridiculed"? I see no evidence, maybe "to the point" comments. Can you quote the comments or answers where you feel you were ridiculed?

Comment: Notice how old that question was

Comment: @James ridiculed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694892/what-is-fabs-in-objective-c/20694918#comment30994797_20694892 and also voted down five times in under ten minutes

Comment: @random yeah but the question pertains to C which goes back a lot further than 2011

Comment: People mentioned that a little simple research would have found the answer for you. SO isn't a tutorial site, I'm afraid, and it shouldn't be used as a substitute for reading basic documentation, and shouldn't replace a basic Google or Bing search as your first resort. (The lack of basic effort to find a solution before posting is probably the reason for the downvotes, but I didn't place any of them and therefore can't say for certain.)

Comment: I think posting "geeeeeez" in the comment was likely one of the reasons for the downvotes. Asking whether you've looked at the documentation is a *very* reasonable question on StackOverflow

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, but I quoted the documentation in my question. The documentation lacked explanation.

Comment: @DavidRobinson it was downvoted 4 times and someone asked why I was coding at all, which led to the _warranted_ "geeeeeez"

Comment: @harkheartfelt: What about a simple Google search for "fabs Objective-C"? What did that turn up for you? (The second hint I got in the Google search box in Firefox suggested "fabs function objective c", and the first result I get from that search is "Objective-C Math functions | Touch Code Magazine", and the second and third are the "other question" you linked as the "good question".)

Comment: @KenWhite turned up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775321/why-does-fabs-return-integer which led to this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ which didn't have anything about fabs, so I took it as opportunity to ask a question

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the search I mentioned turned up the single hit to the SO question you provide. If it did, please include the **exact search phrase you used**, so that I can replicate it. (If it indeed turned up more than one, you clearly didn't do enough research.)

Comment: @KenWhite it turned up all sorts of stuff, that was what I happened to click. Put me on a cross ok?

Comment: Keep in mind that Google tracks your search history, so when a result may turn up first for somebody it may turn up 10000th for someone else. Also, one important part of asking a question on SO is for it to turn up on search engines and and help other people (in a simple elegant Q&A fashion).

Comment: @darkheartfelt: Don't shoot the messenger. :-) You asked why the different treatment, after all. Don't get bent out of shape when we answer you.

Comment: @Dude: That's the very first Objective-C question I've ever Googled, and the first time I've ever heard of "Touch Code Magazine". (I don't develop for Mac/iOS at all.) Not sure how my search history would have been an issue in any way.

Comment: @KenWhite I search for stuff like "javascript run code with array arguments", and google remembers that. So if I search "apply" later, I get the first result as the MDN article on function.prototype.apply. In your case, it may be that because you didn't google Objective-C stuff before, it won't know that you want it now, thus the relevant stuff won't get as good of rankings.

Comment: @Dude: So how does that explain that it **did find it for me immediately**? I got results in hits 1, 2, and 3 for the search. I'm not the one that asked this question, in case you've lost track here. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I haven't lost track. I should also say that other factors should be included, such as how well darkheartfelt could have googled it (You have to know the right keywords and how to phrase it). And how much he googled other competing keywords etc. You got it immediately because your history matched your search.

Comment: @Dude: As I said, I've **never searched for anything related to Objective-C before**, and I provided the **exact search phrase I used** ("fabs Objective-C") and how I used it. How is that knowing the "right keywords"? I took them directly from the poster's question, so it's not something I knew in advance. I chose the function name and the indicated language tag and searched on them.  (IOW, I spent < 30 seconds and found 3 absolutely perfect answers in a single search, with no previous searches on either the language or the function *ever*.)

Comment: @KenWhite Ok, you got the phrase right, and I agree that it isn't hard to get it right. It isn't just about not searching Objective-C before. If you had previously searched for fabs (a different definition) a lot then it could mask the relevant results.

Comment: @Dude: I've never searched for "fabs" before, either. (I knew what it was long before either Objective-C or even the internet existed, so there was no need to search for it.) This is a clear case of the poster searching, checking 1 link in the search results, and then asking the question here instead of exerting any more effort.

Comment: That's the point. IF you did (and as OP might have) it would clutter your results and down-rank the good ones.

Comment: The poster has [already mentioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212773/why-do-similar-questions-get-very-different-responses-on-stackoverflow?noredirect=1#comment684986_212773) that a single link in the results of the search were checked, that led to a single question here, that led to docs on "printf".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that there were a multitude of reasons for the differences between the two. First, the most obvious thing that I can see is that the question that got upvoted is much better for search ranking, there will be many people searching for "How to convert to absolute value in Objective-C", and if you search that, you'll see that the SO question shows up as the first result. Even if you search "What is fabs in objective C", the upvoted question shows up higher.

However, that doesn't mean that your question is somehow terrible, it could just be that the first person to see your question downvoted it, and by herd mentality, it triggered a pile of downvotes, and the exact opposite happened on the other question.

Also, while both questions could have been solved by a simple google search, that question will serve as a canonical reference, yours probably won't

Comment: Thanks. I'm at a loss for why I can't find something to learn from this. I've been on Stack Overflow for six months, never exceeding 50 reputation, and I just lost 20 percent of it in ten minutes.

Comment: We all started there, I was there a few months ago. The best thing you can do is to post clean, well-researched questions, and answering a lot of questions. Your Q/A ratio is pretty good, from what I can see

Comment: thank you I'll keep trying to get better!

Comment: This answer is not exactly what happened. This is a typical situation when an old question is fine because it was in accordance with the rules then, but the new question is not because rules have changed and in addition it is likely to have an exact duplicate. If you copy that high-rep question and ask it again, you'll get -10 votes, I assure you.

Answer (score 7):

> with questions like these, what are you doing looking at the code in the first place?

So it's a bit stern. A friendly translation would be:

> I think your level of expertise is low for this coding language at the moment and you'd be best suited reading some tutorials and learning a bit more first as this is a very beginner question.

The internet is full of "people" and people can be blunt, arrogant, unkind, etc.

However, on Stack (Overflow, Meta, etc), it's not about unkind or arrogant, people are busy, the same questions get asked over and over again, and most people are seasoned professionals in a coding language or multiple, and so their time is precious.

This means that the chatty "frills" you see in forums is not seen here. People post *to the point* replies, factual, and accurate. Sometimes these can be perceived as unkind or grossly unfair, but in reality, they're just accurate and to the point.

So take it with a pinch of salt.

Also, your question is a dupe, which makes people less inclined to help you, be polite, etc.
ie people feel you should spend *your* time researching other questions and answers here and on Google first, before asking for *their* time on a question that is found by easy searches.
Which let's be honest, is only fair right?

Otherwise everyone would just bang out a question and wait for someone to answer it.
This is not how people use the Stack sites, they expect a good question, with code, findings, research etc.

This is likely the reason for the downvotes too. You asked something which a quick search would provide an answer for.

You can be a beginner and ask a noobish question, but only as long as it's not an obvious dupe where you could have found your answer without posting, and it's well laid out, factual and full of the required information.

Just don't be put off. Don't be bothered by people's words, even if harsh. And if accurate (even if harsh or bitter) then just ignore the bluntness and learn from it.

Comment: Where's the dupe?

Comment: His comment was unhelpful and rude and there's no reason for you to come to it's aid. This is BS.

Comment: In which case report it. But don't let it bother you.